# Joining Multiple Associations in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to join tables in posts model id  matching with comment id in comments model.comment model is belonging to post model. my active record query in controller is:

```
    Post.joins(:comments)
```

It generate query like this

```
    SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" INNER JOIN "comments" ON "comments"."post_id" = "post"."id"
```

but I am not able to select  comments.How can I generate a query like below

```
 SELECT * FROM "posts" INNER JOIN "comments" ON "comments"."post_id" = "post"."id"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve the comments data along with posts, you should use `.includes` instead of `.joins`.

```
Post.includes(:comments)
```

Naturally the above will return some posts and you can get to their comments through their relation without another hit to the database.

There's a nice article about includes vs joins [here](http://tomdallimore.com/blog/includes-vs-joins-in-rails-when-and-where/).

Comment: @dinnesh If this answer was sufficient to solve your question, please consider accepting it.

Comment: No,Alex  it generates   query like this                                                                                        SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"
 SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" IN (1, 2, 3)                                                                                                   but  it displaying results as same as SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"  comments  column is not loading

Comment: That should allow you to load comments through posts. `Post.includes(:comments).first.comments` should output the comments for the first post.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.Already I tried with this Post.includes(:comments).first.comments  Alex  It's displaying only comments columns not displaying post columns.

Comment: I want to select "title ,body,comment" from posts,comments model.But I am facing problem only selecting title, body from post or comment from comments model.

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant part of your views where you're trying to use that information.